# Problem about passing graphical code as key value to a tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I want to define a new tcolorbox with a tile pattern watermark using external images or graphical code. There are some separation space among these patterns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    guaguabox/.search also  = {/tcb},
    guaguabox/.cd,
    pictures/.code n args   = {2}{\def\picture@one{#1}
                                  \def\picture@two{#2}},
}
\DeclareTColorBox{guaguabox}{ O{} }{
    code        = {\tcbset{guaguabox/.cd,#1}},
    tile,
    colback     = violet,
    underlay    = {
        \path[fill tile picture={
            \newlength\pic@width
            \setlength{\pic@width}{1cm}
            \def\pic@one{
                \IfFileExists
                    {\picture@one}
                    {\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@one}};}
                    {\picture@one}}
            \def\pic@two{
                \IfFileExists
                    {\picture@two}
                    {\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@two}};}
                    {\picture@two}}
            \tikzset{every node/.style={opacity=0.5,anchor=center}}
            \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (4\pic@width,4\pic@width);
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\pic@width,yshift=\pic@width]
                \pic@one
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3\pic@width,yshift=3\pic@width]
                \pic@one
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3\pic@width,yshift=\pic@width]
                \pic@two
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\pic@width,yshift=3\pic@width]
                \pic@two
            \end{scope}
        }]
        (interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
    },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{guaguabox}[pictures  = {\path[fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}
                              {\path[fill=gray] (0.5,0.5) circle (1);},
                  coltext   = white]
\lipsum[1]
\end{guaguabox}
\end{document}
```

Saved as UTF-8 code, and compiled by pdflatex.
If I replace these graphical code by external image names, it's ok.

To verify graphical code as key value , I made a small MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{/test/.cd,pics/.code n args = {2}{\tikz #1\hspace{2cm}\tikz #2}}
\tikzset{/test/.cd,pics={\fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);}{\path[fill=gray] (0.5,0.5) circle (1);}}
\end{document}
```

The second MWE is OK, why the first MWE dosn't work?

Comment: First try to make sure the MWE actually produce the error you claimed. Now I get "violet2 is undefined" and "lipsum is undefined" instead.

Comment: `\IfFileExists{<file name>}{<true block>}{<else block>}` is not as powerful as you may imagine. It will NOT run `<else block>` if `<file name>` is not fully expandable, which in your code is some tikz code. You must use another method to decide if `\picture@one` is a file name or not. Or provide different keys. For example, testing if `\tikz` is in it: `\expandafter\in@\expandafter\tikz\expandafter{\picture@one}\ifin@ <true block>\else <else block>\fi` or some latex3 equivalence. Also, nesting `\tikz` is NOT officially supported, hence may result in unexpected results.

Comment: @user202729 There are some mistakes in the first MWE, I've revised. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I haven't read the `tikz` package source code, is that all of the `tikz` graphical code expanded has `\tikz` in it? In this scene, the graphical code is just only a few `\path` , `\node`, or `\draw` etc., commands, does not include `\tikz`.

Comment: @HZ.Zhang Sorry I forget there's eTeX primitive `\detokenize`. `\IfFileExists{\detokenize{\picture@one}}` will do the trick.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes, `\IfFileExists{\detokenize{\picture@one}}` does work when `\picture@one` is some graphical code, but when `\picture@one` is an external image filename, `{<true block>}` in `\IfFileExists` command does not run. The error information shows :Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three changes are made:

- Move `\newlength\pic@width` outside of `\DeclareTColorBox{guaguabox}{ O{} }{...}`. It should be declared only once.
- Change `\IfFileExists{\picture@one}` to `\IfFileExists{\detokenize\expandafter{\picture@one}}` to allow arbitrary code being detected as a file name.
- Change

  ```tex
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@one}};
  % to
  \node at (0,0) {\expanded{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@one}}};
  ```

  `\includegraphics` can't have its mandatory argument stored in a macro. You have to expand it (`\picture@one`) first.

Full example with all the changes applied:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\tcbset{
    guaguabox/.search also  = {/tcb},
    guaguabox/.cd,
    pictures/.code n args   = {2}{\def\picture@one{#1}
                                  \def\picture@two{#2}},
}

            \newlength\pic@width

\DeclareTColorBox{guaguabox}{ O{} }{
    code        = {\tcbset{guaguabox/.cd,#1}},
    tile,
    colback     = violet,
    underlay    = {
        \path[fill tile picture={
            \setlength{\pic@width}{1cm}
            \def\pic@one{%
                \IfFileExists
                    {\detokenize\expandafter{\picture@one}}
                    {\node at (0,0) {\expanded{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@one}}};}
                    {\picture@one}}
            \def\pic@two{%
                \IfFileExists
                    {\detokenize\expandafter{\picture@two}}
                    {\node at (0,0) {\expanded{\noexpand\includegraphics[width=\pic@width]{\picture@two}}};}
                    {\picture@two}}
            \tikzset{every node/.style={opacity=0.5,anchor=center}}
            \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (4\pic@width,4\pic@width);
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\pic@width,yshift=\pic@width]
                \pic@one
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3\pic@width,yshift=3\pic@width]
                \pic@one
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3\pic@width,yshift=\pic@width]
                \pic@two
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[xshift=\pic@width,yshift=3\pic@width]
                \pic@two
            \end{scope}
        }]
        (interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
    },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
tikz codes
\begin{guaguabox}[pictures  = {\path[fill=gray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}
                              {\path[fill=gray] (0.5,0.5) circle (1);},
                  coltext   = white]
\lipsum[1]
\end{guaguabox}

Image names
\begin{guaguabox}[pictures  = {example-image-a}
                              {example-image-b},
                  coltext   = white]
\lipsum[1]
\end{guaguabox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A bit lazy to do refactoring, so let it be.

Comment: Thank you for your help, It's so great!